Login Sequence Recorder with React
I want to make login sequence recorder with React. I tried iframe,window.open etc but ı couldn't achieve. I tried to use react and websocket connection but ı can't take sequences in target url. I tried to use selenium web driver in node.js but it works in server that's why ı couldn't open window side of client because client must fill required inputs and click buttons. Which technologies can ı use or what can ı do ı don't know. Please can u help me ?
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function WebSocketComponent() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("https://facebook.com/login");
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("browse");
  const ws = useRef(null);
  const iframeRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    ws.current = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

    ws.current.onopen = () => {
      console.log("WebSocket connected");
    };

    ws.current.onmessage = (event) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log("Received:", data);

      if (data.cmd === "navigate") {
        if (iframeRef.current) {
          iframeRef.current.src = data.payload.url;
        }
      } else if (data.cmd === "modeChanged") {
        setMode(data.payload.mode);
        console.log("Mode changed to:", data.payload.mode);
      }
    };

    ws.current.onclose = () => {
      console.log("WebSocket disconnected");
    };

    // Dinleyici ekle
    const handleMessage = (event) => {
      if (event.origin !== new URL(url).origin) return; 
      console.log("Message from iframe:", event.data);

      if (ws.current && ws.current.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        ws.current.send(
          JSON.stringify({
            cmd: "recordedData",
            payload: event.data,
          })
        );
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage);

    return () => {
      if (ws.current) {
        ws.current.close();
      }
      window.removeEventListener("message", handleMessage);
    };
  }, [url]);

  const handleUrlSubmit = () => {
    if (ws.current && ws.current.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      const payload = {
        cmd: "urlgoto",
        payload: { url: url },
      };
      ws.current.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    }
  };

  const handleModeChange = () => {
    if (ws.current && ws.current.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      const payload = {
        cmd: "setMode",
        payload: { mode: "record" },
      };
      ws.current.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={url}
        onChange={(e) => setUrl(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="URL "
      />
      <button onClick={handleUrlSubmit}>Open URL</button>
      <button onClick={handleModeChange}>Record</button>

      <iframe
        ref={iframeRef}
        title="Interaction Frame"
        width="800"
        height="600"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default WebSocketComponent;

This is side of React.
const { Builder, By, Key } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const WebSocket = require("ws");

(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
  let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

  ws.on("open", function open() {
    console.log("WebSocket connected");
  });

  ws.on("message", function incoming(data) {
    console.log("Received:", data);
  });

  try {
    await driver.get("http://localhost:5173/");

    // Iframe'a geçiş yap
    let iframe = await driver.findElement(By.css("iframe"));
    await driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

   
    
    ws.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        cmd: "recordedData",
        payload: "Giriş yapıldı",
      })
    );
  } finally {
    // WebDriver'ı kapat
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();

This is side of Node.js Backend.
When client open a url, I want to listen all and save login sequences.

What is "login sequence recorder"? Are you trying to create a page which steals credentials?

Not steal. For example You have a website. You will enter your website's url and login. I will save this sequences for cyber security.  So I will be able to test in your website.
For example Acunetix https://www.acunetix.com/support/docs/login-sequence-recorder/

i don't think iframes are the way to go, you can't really acces any contents of a page from other page, and communication via postMessage would require the login page to implement this mechanism, which is awkward to ask for. Notice that Acunetix require an installation of an external program which probably has a browser built in.
Perhaps check out Playwright - it's a testing toolset. One of it's features is code generation - it allows you to record actions and save them in a form of a test code.
